# OpenVPN windows client remove (cached?) effect of config files (*.opvn)

Tags: openvpn

I have an OpenVPN client working on a Windows 7 machine.  It works because of some config files (`*.ovpn`, `*.crt`, `*.key`, and `*.conf`).  Now for troubleshooting purposes I want to test with another set of config files.  So I saved away the original config files (originally located in `C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config`, now I moved them into a sub-folder called `old_files`).  However, I noticed that files are still taking effect -- my client still connects with the old settings.  It seems the values of the config files have been cached some where.  How do I clean up this cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I am answer my own question here ...)

Okay I found out that the OpenVPN client seems to be able to find the `*.ovpn` file under `C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config` even if the file is located in a sub-directory from there.  So to solve the problem, I had to move the file out to a completely unrelated folder.

Thanks for your kind attention!

Answer (score 4):

I just wanna add some things. I use the "Import files ... " in client list in Taskbar. And at first I cannot remove any of them because it's not existed in `C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config` like normal.

And I found out another folder they also used to get config: `C:\Users\<your user name>\OpenVPN\config` . Just delete the config file you want and done.